# Eliminating small polygon feature after converting grid to shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have created crop suitability map (grid) by using Ecocrop model and converted to shapefile. However, it appeared to have many small polygon features in the study area as attached.

Would it be possible to correct or eliminate these small polygon features?

[image: Example]

Comment: Which polygons are you talking about, the dark in the light green or the light in the dark green, or both? Simply removing them (easiest option) would leave holes of no data, is that what you want or do you want to re-code them so that they are the same as their surroundings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you want to do is make the small light green polygons be part of the dark green area, and make the small dark green polygons be par of the light green area, you need to use the [eliminate tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/eliminate.htm).

The easiest way to do this is to select all the small polygons what you want to get rid of, and then run the eliminate tool.  The tool will only be applied to the selected data.

However, to me it looks like you might need to do some data cleaning first as it looks like you might have some self-intersections in your data.

[image]

So your first step is to correct any self intersections you might have.  Using a tool like the [cut polygon tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-a-polygon.htm) should make this process fairly quick for you.

You then need to make sure that your small polygons are individual features, rather than multipolygons.  You can do this using the [multipart to singlepart tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm).

The final step is to then use the eliminate tool as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eliminate polygon part tool, which requires an advanced licence (so does eliminate suggested by @Dan_h_b) but then you can avoid the multipart to single part step.

If you don't have an advanced licence, and because you don't have many polygons, you could use the merge tool in an edit session. (you then need to "explode" your multipart polygons, or run the multipart to single part tool.